# How to recover fragments after screen orientation replacement

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

I have an activity with two fragments: DogFragment, LegoFragment. In portrait mode I show DogFragment and in landscape mode I show LegoFragment. My problem is that the fragments aren’t remembering their states after rotation. Is there a way to save the fragment’s states? Understand that the activity is recreated during orientation changes and that based on the orientation I create and attach either DogFragment or LegoFragment to the activity.

Here is the activity’s `onCreate` method where I add the fragments.

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 
     Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) { 
   addDogFragment(); 
  } else {
       addLegoFragment();
   }
 }

private void addDogFragment() {
  DogFragment fragment = DogFragment.newInstance(null, null);    
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
  replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
 }  

private void addLegoFragment() {
   LegoFragment fragment = LegoFragment.newInstance(null, null);     
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
  replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
 }
```

I know that the FragmentManager has a copy of my fragments. But I am not sure the best way to solve this problem. If I call `replace` with a tag, do I just findByTag and then call replace again? Or is there a standard way to do these things?

Comment: you should add that code in onConfiguration change as well.

Comment: @k0sh When you say `that` code, which code are you referring to? The portion inside onCreate? Could you please provide some explanation as to why that change would solve the problem?

Comment: yes, the checking for orientation changes, just add it to onConfiguration change, as this method will always be triggered when there is orientation change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, create a similar function for LegoFragment

```
private void setDogFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment removeFragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("lego");
    if (removeFragment!=null) {
        transaction.detach(removeFragment);
    }
    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("dog");
    if (fragment != null) {
        transaction.attach(fragment);
    } else {
        fragment = new DogFragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment,
                "dog");
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: You are awesome!!! check and +1! This works great: And it makes sense. So thank you for a clear code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 
 Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    attachFragment(R.id.fragment_container, "dogFragment",     DogFragment.class.getName());
else 
    attachFragment(R.id.fragment_container, "legoFragment", LegoFragment.class.getName());


private FragmentTransaction mCurTransaction;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
public void attachFragment(int containerViewId, String tag, String fragmentClassName){
    if (mFragmentManager == null)
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); // or getFragmentManager();

    if (mCurTransaction == null)
        mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    // Do we already have this fragment?
    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if (fragment != null){
        mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
    }else {
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, fragmentClassName);
        mCurTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment, tag);
    }
}
```